# How do you make a bat file that can take 1 file and then use the directory and the file name again in the command but while changing the file format

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm currently trying to convert a lot of files into another format using an executable. When running the command on cmd, it goes as follows :

```
executable_name.exe -e "directory\filename.old_format" "directory\filename.new_format"
```

How can i write a bat so that it can reuse the directory, filename, and format name so that it can be re-executed like the example above, only with a changed file format? Also, how can i do this with multiple files?

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "delims=" %%b in ('dir /b /s /a-d "directory\*.old_format"') do executablename.exe -e "%%b" "%%~dpnb.new_format"
```

as a batch line should accomplish this task, in general.

See `for /?` from the prompt for documentation about the hieroglyphs or hundreds of examples on SO.

Note that I've used `/s` on the `dir` command. This scans subdirectories, too.

If you want to scan just one directory,

1. Omit the `/s` from the `dir` command.
2. Use `"dirname\%%b"` in place of `"%%b"` to specify the source file
3. Use `"dirname2%%~nb.new_format" to specify the destination